# Extract floats from a column of strings and round to 2 decimal places

Tags: python, pandas, floating-point

If i have a data frame with values in a column

```
4.5678
5
7.987.998
```

I want to extract data for only 2 values after the decimal

```
4.56
5
7.98
```

The data is stored as a string. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you !

Comment: A "df"? I assume you mean a data-frame? Assuming you are using `pandas`? These are important tags.

Comment: Yes. I meant a data frame. Thank you ! Will remember that

Comment: @beginnerdscientist The accepted answer does not answer your question, it has nothing to do with pandas. Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46553671/4909087

Comment: You cannot have two "decimal signs" in a number, so the "." in "7.987.998" is probably a "grouping separator" and the value is about 8 million

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
str = "7.987.998"
ind = str.find('.')
if ind > 0:
  res = str[:ind+3]
```

Comment: find returns the index of the first occurence of the special character you are looking for, here `.`

Comment: This has nothing to do with pandas and does not answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

```
print(s) 
0       4.5678
1            5
2    7.987.998
Name: 0, dtype: object

print(type(s))
Out[152]: pandas.core.series.Series
```

---

Using `str.extract` + `round`:

```
r = s.str.extract('(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)', \
           expand=False).astype(float).round(2)
print(r)
0    4.57
1    5.00
2    7.99
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```

Unfortunately, the 5 cannot be an integer as your expected output describes, that would lead to mixed types and is generally discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_two_spaces(input):
    input_list = input.split('.')
    if len(input_list) >= 2:
        return input_list[0] + '.' + input_list[1][:2]
    return input
```

I'll break down what's happening here:

1. we split the string into a list of strings around the period character.
2. we see how many items are in that list:
3. if there are 2 or more, we return the entire first string, a period, and the first 2 characters of the second string
4. if there are not, we just return the original input.

Answer (score 0):

Another **pandas** approach:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(['4.5678','5','7.987.998'], columns=['A'])
s = df['A'].replace(to_replace='^(\d+\.\d+)\.\d+', value=r'\1', regex=True)\
    .astype('float').map('{:,.2f}'.format)

print(s)
```

The output:

```
0    4.57
1    5.00
2    7.99
Name: A, dtype: object
```