# How to have the same number of decimal places when converting from float to string in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, string

I have an issue when converting float column to string in pandas. I want to have the same number of decimal places (e.g.2) in string to later add currency sign.

```
import pandas as pd

Data = {'Product': ['ABC','XYZ'],
          'Price': ['250.00','270.43']}

df = pd.DataFrame(Data)
df['Price'] = df['Price'].astype(float)
df['Product'] = df['Product'].astype(str)

print(df)
print(df.dtypes)

df['Price'] = df['Price'].astype(str)

print(df)
print(df.dtypes)
```

What i get:

```
  Product   Price
0     ABC  250.00
1     XYZ  270.43

Product     object
Price      float64
dtype: object

  Product   Price
0     ABC   250.0
1     XYZ  270.43

Product    object
Price      object
dtype: object
```

I try to get 250.00 as string.
Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do an apply with `format`:

```
df['Price'] = df['Price'].apply("{:.02f}".format)
```

Output:

```
  Product   Price
0     ABC  250.00
1     XYZ  270.43
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a duplicate of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46553450/extract-floats-from-a-column-of-strings-and-round-to-2-decimal-places)

```
df['Price'] = df['Price'].astype(str)
df["Price"] = df['Price'].str.extract('(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)', \
           expand=False).astype(float).round(2)
print(df)
print(df.dtypes)
```